# How do I compile Boost into a static library?

Tags: c++, boost

I am new to C++ and would like to use the boost networking libraries on my Ubuntu laptop. I downloaded the Boost library tar.gz file and opened it up. The boost library had a bunch of .hpp files in the boost folder and in the libs folder. I tried running the command: g++ file.cpp -o file -I ~/Desktop/boost/lib but gcc wouldn't compile it. I then got the idea to compile the library into a static .a file but I don't know where to start. How would I go about doing this with the ar rcs command?

Comment: Most of Boost is header only. Boost comes with a build system which can build its various sub-libraries as static libraries for you. Have you followed Boost's getting started guide?

Comment: Boost is already packaged on Ubuntu. `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

Comment: I would like to do this on my own without cmake or apt just to ensure I can.

Answer (score 0):

Boost is already packaged on Ubuntu. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```